# trigger in sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server

I want to create trigger for one table for insertion...If i insert records in one table then that same records should be inserted to another one......how?

and also explain about triggers

Answer (score 2):

All you need to know about triggers, without having to wade through Microsoft speak, including how to create them in SQL Server.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_trigger

Comment: agreed, but to someone who is just starting out, it might not be the easiest to understand

Answer (score 1):

It should be something like

```
CREATE TRIGGER TableInserted ON TableInsert
AFTER INSERT
AS
INSERT INTO OtherTable SELECT * FROM inserted
```

Answer (score -1):

[This](http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/SQL-Server/Using-Triggers-In-MS-SQL-Server/1/) article covers all the basics of creating triggers.

Though for you task i think a stored procedure doing both inserts will be better, because what if one insert succeeded and the other failed? it will create inconsistency in your data. See [here](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/articles/dba/stored_procedures_basics_p1.aspx) for stored procedures.